# 400 Bad Request on Instagram Photo Source

Tags: image, instagram, photo

My website not showing the image from the Instagram source.
Here's my HTML:

```
<img src="https://www.instagram.com/p/CG0N-zBLui1/media/?size=l" class="photo">
```

On my browser's console, it shows like this:
[Here's the snip of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AvwZ.png)

I don't understand why it's 400 (bad request) because it happens just a week ago and not a problem since I build my website.

Answer (score 0):

The `/media/` endpoint has been deprecated as you can see when opening the URL in incognito mode:

> This endpoint is deprecated. Please read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed to learn how to migrate your endpoint.